# Chat App with Monaca

Tags: node.js, cordova, websocket, monaca

i am a beginner at developing hybrid apps. And i came across of this magnificent cloud-based framework named Monaca. Now the issue is this, the Backend it provides is not useable for my chat application(well if there is a miss from my side feel free to comment), so my question is how can i approach this issue? i have heard of Backend as Service(BaaS), PubNub, Jabber and more but its really expensive on the long run. There is a solution with node.js and websockets. But i don´t know how to use them with Monaca. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any issue to integrate any backend service to your Monaca project, as long as the service provides a JS API. You just need to follow the API integration docs and integrate it in Monaca. Did you already took a look at Azure? There is already a tutorial on Onsen UI & Monaca Blog:

https://onsen.io/blog/tutorial-todo-app-with-onsen-ui-and-azure/

Hope it helps!